# belongs_to class_name namespace issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models `Foo::Bar` and `Bar`. `Foo::Bar` belongs_to `Bar`. The problem arises when you attempt to call `@bar.bar` (@bar in this case is an instance of `Foo::Bar`).

If you define `:class_name` using quotes then all works as expected but if you **don't** use quotes then you'll get back a `Foo::Bar` instance instead of a `Bar` instance.

Why the difference? Is this a bug in Rails (I'm using Rails 4.0.0RC1 by the way)?

**Doesn't Work**

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar,
  class_name: ::Bar
end
```

**Works**

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar,
  class_name: '::Bar'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I think i get the difference.

```
Bar.to_s -> "Bar"
::Bar.to_s -> "Bar"
```

So i think rails is doing a to_s somewhere that converts your ::Bar into Bar.
So its better to use string for class_name to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect `::Bar` to work?

When I look into [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), I see that `:class_name`s are strings everywhere. I don't see any single usage of something like `::Bar`.

Comment: I've been using it in my app in multiple other places with no issues up until this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it worked in cases where the association name is different from the class name?

Comment: Yes. I'm positive. I have a `has_many :current_jobs` where `:class_name` is `Job` and it works with no problems.